adding Epson Stylus C88+ printer driver
I'm running system 24.04 on an HP Elitebook. I have an Epson Stylus C88+ inkjet printer and can connect it via USB. The problem is finding a printer driver for it. I have queried the database and several dozens of Epson printers are listed, including several Epson Stylus printers...but not specifically the Stylus C88. Inquiry with the Epson website for Linux drivers for the Stylus C88 reveals no Linux drivers for this model. This is an adequate printer for my needs and wants. While I can run it as a shared printer on my ancient imac, I was hoping to be able to run it directly from the Ubuntu computer without having to have the imac up and running.
Is there some other driver that might work...an equivalent or compatible driver?
I have queried the driver database and there are 21 Epson Stylus printers listed, none of them the Stylus 88. I have tried selecting a few of the listed Epson Stylus drivers, but the printer would not respond or print. I am apparently doing something wrong, but what? I have no Ubuntu ego to defend, and am always a beginner and student.
I did some searching online and found a printer driver for the Epson Stylus 88, marketed specifically for Ubuntu. It is not free, but does have a generous 30 day trial period. I downloaded a copy of this program and have tried printing with it. I am pleased with the results and am going to buy the license for it. It has been straightforward and I will read the manual for it, to wring the most out of it. I will post more results, later.

Ubuntu should automatically find the printer and print without any additional driver. Open Settings and select Printers from the left panel. See if the printer is already discovered there. Try to print using the discovered printer. Then update your question with the new information.

Epson Stylus C88 is already included in Ubuntu 24.04.
